# Can I turn off create-react-app chunking mechanism?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, chunks, chunking

I am setting up my React app project using `create-react-app`.

I was wondering if there is a way to turn-off the chunking mechanism that is built-in into the react scripts.  The thing is that I need to fix the name of the bundle created on the build.

Comment: Why do you have to fix the name?

Comment: I am developing VS Code extension and I need to import bundle. So, I need to know the name of it.

Comment: Has anyone been able to do this with react-scripts 5.0.0 ?

Answer (score 16):

It can be done by extending your CRA with `react-app-rewired` package which allows you to modify webpack config.

Changes needed to remove hash in build file names.

1. Install react-app-rewired

`npm install react-app-rewired --save-dev`

2. create `config-overrides.js` file in your root folder (where `package.json` is)
3. place the following code to the `config-overrides.js` file. It keeps all CRA settings, only remove the hash part from filenames.

```
    module.exports = function override(config, env) {
        config.output = {
            ...config.output, // copy all settings
            filename: "static/js/[name].js",
            chunkFilename: "static/js/[name].chunk.js",
        };
        return config;
    };
```

4. use the new config. In the `package.json` file in `scripts` section replace `"build": "react-scripts build",` with `"build": "react-app-rewired build",`

Unless you are going to change more configuration, it is enough to only use `react-app-rewired` in `build`. Otherwise replace `react-scripts` with `react-app-rewired` in others scripts except `eject`

Comment: Any idea how to change CSS assets too?

Comment: same problem here, how to change CSS assets?

Comment: See my answer below for a suggested version that also handles css and media files

Answer (score 8):

As others have pointed out you can try this with `react-app-rewired` instead of ejecting. Here is a version that also handles css and media files:

After installing `npm install react-app-rewired --save-dev` I created a `config-overrides.js` with the following content:

```js
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
    if (env !== "production") {
        return config;
    }

    // Get rid of hash for js files
    config.output.filename = "static/js/[name].js"
    config.output.chunkFilename = "static/js/[name].chunk.js"

    // Get rid of hash for css files
    const miniCssExtractPlugin = config.plugins.find(element => element.constructor.name === "MiniCssExtractPlugin");
    miniCssExtractPlugin.options.filename = "static/css/[name].css"
    miniCssExtractPlugin.options.chunkFilename = "static/css/[name].css"

    // Get rid of hash for media files
    config.module.rules[1].oneOf.forEach(oneOf => {
        if (!oneOf.options ||  oneOf.options.name !== "static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]") {
            return;
        }
        oneOf.options.name = "static/media/[name].[ext]"
    });

    return config;
};
```

Answer (score 7):

I've found that you can disable chunking by setting `splitChunks` webpack configuration. For more details check https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5306#issuecomment-431431877

However, this does not remove the `contenthash` part from the bundle name and you will still have that random string in the name.

To remove this, go to your `webpack.config` and edit the bundle name

`'static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].js'` => `'static/js/[name].js'`

Comment: Thanks, you probably saved us the ability to use the embedded React app in our project. Worked like a charm for issues related to embedding React app inside iframe.

Answer (score 7):

This is extended and improved version of Darko's answer. I created it mostly to save time for others who is not fully satisfied with solution mentioned in [this comment](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5306#issuecomment-431431877) and didn't have a patience to dig to [this comment](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5306#issuecomment-433425838) that solved the issue in much nicer way.

Main idea of this "hacky" approach is to re-write standard `react-scripts`'s `webpack` configuration on the fly and inject it back to original scripts.

For that you would need to install `rewire` package from `npmjs.org`, like so:

```
npm install rewire --save-dev
```

Then you create separate build script that will will "wrap" original `react build` script and make sure that it will relieve corrected `webpack` configuration. Conventional way is to save this file inside `./scripts` folder. So let's call it `./scripts/build.js`. It's content:

```js
const rewire = require('rewire');
const path = require('path');

// Pointing to file which we want to re-wire — this is original build script
const defaults = rewire('react-scripts/scripts/build.js');

// Getting configuration from original build script
let config = defaults.__get__('config');

// If we want to move build result into a different folder, we can do that!
// Please note: that should be an absolute path!
config.output.path = path.join(path.dirname(__dirname), 'custom/target/folder');

// If we want to rename resulting bundle file to not have hashes, we can do that!
config.output.filename = 'custom-bundle-name.js';

// And the last thing: disabling splitting
config.optimization.splitChunks = {
    cacheGroups: {
        default: false,
    },
};
config.optimization.runtimeChunk = false;
```

Then, we should use this build script instead of standard one in our `packages.json`, something like so:

```
...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "node ./scripts/build.js",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
...
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a hack without needing *eject*:

1. `yarn add --dev rewire`
2. create file in root and name it `build-non-split.js`
3. fill inside it by below codes:

   ```
   const rewire = require('rewire');
   const defaults = rewire('react-scripts/scripts/build.js');
   let config = defaults.__get__('config');

   config.optimization.splitChunks = {
       cacheGroups: {
           default: false,
       },
   };

   config.optimization.runtimeChunk = false;
   ```
4. change the build script inside your `package.json` to:

   ```
   "build": "node ./scripts/build-non-split.js",
   ```
5. `yarn build`

Comment: Possible source of this solution: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5306#issuecomment-433425838

Comment: how do you make it work for css files as well ?

Comment: @MichelHua, I used css-in-js, if you want use other CSS methods, thats ok, you should import CSS as css-modules, like: `import styles from './styles.css';` and then in using you must use it like: `<Comp className={styles.container}>`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to turn off chunking but what you could do try achieve you goal

Update to latest react and react-dom , run 'yarn react@next react-dom@next' (or npm command to do same)

You should now have the latest react versions - so you can code split using React.lazy/React.Suspense, use hooks and so on.

So now you can name your chunks using (component or dependency examples below)

```
 const MyComp = lazy(() =>   import(/* webpackChunkName: 'MyChunkNmame'
*/ './MyComp'), );

const myLib= await import(/* webpackChunkName: "myLib" */ 'myLib');
```

If you have an issue with errors when using the import syntax you need to use the babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import plugin. Put the "babel" field in your package json.

Now you can name your chunks and implement the latest way to code split - hope that helps.  Here is a link to React.lazy React.Suspense - https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/23/react-v-16-6.html

Comment: It is not what I am looking for but, thank you. Naming the chunks can definitely come handy in some cases. I've actually found a couple of GitHub discussions with similar questions. I'll write an answer soon.